# s-t min-cut in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to find a  minimum s-t cut in a graph. According to the max-flow-min-cut theorem, from a maximum flow, I can find min cut. I didn't find built-in function to calculate the min-cut, only built-in function to calculate a max flow.

I have implemented the s-t min-cut in a directed graph(using the explanation from this [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-cut-in-a-directed-graph/)). The code is below

Graph creation:

```
 checkGrap = 
   Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
   weighsToEdgesVT = {12, 10, 4, 9, 7, 14, 16, 13, 20, 4};

  testGrapWe = 
  Graph[VertexList[checkGrap], EdgeList[checkGrap], 
   EdgeWeight -> weighsToEdgesVT, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Residual graph calculation:

```
flowData = FindMaximumFlow[checkGrap, 5, 6, "OptimumFlowData", EdgeCapacity -> weithsToEdgesVT];
flowMAtrix = flowData["FlowMatrix"];
originalMatrix = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[testGrapWe];
residualMatrix = (N[originalMatrix - flowMAtrix]);
mc = SparseArray[ ArrayRules[residualMatrix] /. {0. -> Infinity}, 
Dimensions[residualMatrix]];
```

Nodes reachable from source:

```
residualGraph = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[mc, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
nodes = Reap[BreadthFirstScan[residualGraph,5, {"DiscoverVertex" -> 
(Sow[#1] &)}]][[2, 1]]
```

The cut

```
 cut = EdgeList[checkGrap, 
  DirectedEdge[Alternatives @@ nodes, 
   Alternatives @@ 
    Complement[VertexOutComponent[checkGrap, nodes], nodes]]]
```

Any suggestion how to speed up the code( I want to run it on a graph with ~30000 nodes and ~100000 edges)

Comment: Thanks @kglr, but according to documentation 'FindVertexCut[g, s, t]' calculate the set of graphs' separator.

Comment: You are looking for `FindEdgeCut`, but it does not seem to return the correct result here (as opposed to `EdgeConnectivity`, which does).

Comment: Given the rather buggy state of this functionality in Mathematica, I'll expose igraph's max flow / min cut functionality in the next version of IGraph/M. It's really sad when a package has to be used not to add extra functionality but to work around the myriads of bugs that make the built-in functions unusable.

Comment: Added to IGraph/M. Contact me directly if you're interested in testing the development version. http://i.stack.imgur.com/5vKEE.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find a minimum s-t edge cut, it should be possible to use [`FindEdgeCut`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindEdgeCut.html). It is explicitly stated in the documentation that it supports edge weights:

> For weighted graphs, FindEdgeCut gives an edge cut with the smallest sum of edge weights.

*However, it is buggy.*

This is your graph:

```
Graph[testGrapWe, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[`EdgeConnectivity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeConnectivity.html) gives a correct result:

```
EdgeConnectivity[testGrapWe, 5, 6]

(* 23 *)
```

But not `FindEdgeCut`:

```
FindEdgeCut[testGrapWe, 5, 6]
(* {5 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 3} *)
```

These two edges have a total weight of 29, not 23.

Let's see if the issue gets fixed for the next version ...

---

In the meantime, you can use the latest version of [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) to find a minimum cut.  IGraph/M has separate functions for edge connectivity (i.e. unweighted edge cut) and minimum cut (i.e. weighted).

The connectivity is 2 because these vertices can be disconnected by the removal of only 2 edges.

```
IGEdgeConnectivity[testGrapWe, 5, 6]
(* 2 *)
```

But if we go for the minimum total weight cut, we need to remove 3 edges:

```
IGMinimumCut[testGrapWe, 5, 6]
(* {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6} *)

IGMinimumCutValue[testGrapWe, 5, 6]
(* 23. *)
```

The performance is reasonable on large graphs:

```
bigGraph = 
  ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "CondensedMatterCollaborations2005"}];

{VertexCount[bigGraph], EdgeCount[bigGraph]}
(* {40421, 175692} *)

IGEdgeWeightedQ[bigGraph]
(* True *)

IGMinimumCutValue[bigGraph, 10, 1000] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.13, 13.6} *)

IGMinimumCut[bigGraph, 10, 1000] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.17, {1000 \[UndirectedEdge] 999, 
  1000 \[UndirectedEdge] 485, 1000 \[UndirectedEdge] 484, 
  1000 \[UndirectedEdge] 200, 3797 \[UndirectedEdge] 485, 
  3797 \[UndirectedEdge] 484, 1442 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000, 
  2742 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000, 3032 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000, 
  7601 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000, 7601 \[UndirectedEdge] 3797, 
  12371 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000, 12371 \[UndirectedEdge] 3797, 
  17309 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000, 17741 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000, 
  24536 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000, 34123 \[UndirectedEdge] 1000}} *)
```

Note that in principle a built-in function can always be faster than an IGraph/M function because IGraph/M needs to convert the graph to igraph's internet representation.  This can be slow, especially considering that Mathematica provides to *fast* API to convert graphs to a form amenable to processing in C code.  A significant amount of time is spent in converting the graph.

In this specific case, I believe this to be the reason why `EdgeConnecvitiy` is more than twice faster.

```
EdgeConnectivity[bigGraph, 10, 1000] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.054, 13.6} *)
```

Let us thus hope that the bug in `FindEdgeCut` will be fixed in the next version of Mathematica!  Note that I exposed this functionality in IGraph/M specifically because of this bug—I usually avoid duplicating existing functionality without good reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're life saver :)

Comment: Dear Szabolcs, I was just looking for min cut functions in Mathematica. I think, please correct me if I am wrong, that FindEdgeCuts is giving the correct answer according to the documentation, which says that it finds the cut with the least weight in the graph, a cut being a set of edges whose removal disconnects the graph. The total of 23 is through the removal of edges (2,3), (3,4), but this is not a "cut" however, (5,1), (5, 3) is a cut whose weight is 29. Need your valuable input, please.

Comment: @Iconoclast (2,3) and (3,4) does not sum to 23. Did you mean to type different edges? However, (1,2), (4,2), (4,6) does sum to 23. The removal of these does make 6 unreachable from 5. Note that with the 3-argument syntax, we look for cuts that make one vertex unreachable from another, not for cuts that disconnect the graph. This graph is already not connected.

Comment: yeah sorry my bad...just realized this now.